# Deixar um menu li com treeview ativo após reload da página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um menu em um `Sidebar` utilizando `<li>` e `<ul>`, quando eu clico em algum a página é atualizada, porque utilizo um link `<a>` no meu.

eu estou usando o seguinte javasscript para atualizar o menu ativo :

```
    $('li').each(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href')) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Esse modelo fuciona bem para os menus `<li>` normais , mas quando tenho um

como este :

```
<li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-group" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>Partners</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" ></i>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Parceiro" , new { Area="Unidade" })"><i class="fa fa-list" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>List Partners</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("NovoParceiro", "Parceiro" , new { Area="Unidade" })"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>Register a new Partner</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

ele não muda o `<li>` ele volta ao padrão, gostaria de saber como fazer para deixar o esse item como ativo. Vi varias respostas mas não consegui entender nenhuma.

assim é como esta a minha pagina:

```
 <li style="margin-top:45px;font:normal" class="active"><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard" , new { Area="Unidade" })><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="color:#4b676f"></i> Statics and Reports</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Informacoes" , new {Area="Unidade" })"><i class="fa fa-home" style="color:#4b676f" ></i> <span> Falcon Company</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Agendamento" , new {PaginaAtual = 0 , Area="Unidade" })"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>Jobs Schedule</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-stethoscope" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>Employee</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Profissional" , new {PaginaAtual = 0 , Area="Unidade" })><i class="fa fa-list" style="color:#4b676f"></i> List Employees</a></li>
            <li><a href=@Url.Action("NovoProfissional", "Profissional" , new { Area="Unidade" })><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color:#4b676f"></i>Register a new Employee</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="~/Content/imagens/IconesDashboard/dashboard.png" style="height:13px;margin-right:9px"> <span>Client</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Empresa" , new {PaginaAtual = 0 , Area="Unidade" })> Client List</a>
            <li><a href=@Url.Action("NovaEmpresa", "Empresa" , new { Area="Unidade" })>Register a new Client</a></li>
            @*<li><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard" , new { Area="Unidade" })> Outras Informacoes</a></li>*@
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-group" style="color:#4b676f"></i> <span>Partners</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" ></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Parceiro" , new { Area="Unidade" })"> <span>List Partners</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("NovoParceiro", "Parceiro" , new { Area="Unidade" })"></i> <span>Register a new Partner</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vais ter que gravar essa informação no browser do cliente (ou por cookies, ou por localStorage, ou por alguma maneira que aches aceitável) e quando fazes load à página verificar se essa preferencia existe e se sim, então seleciona o valor que é igual à informaçao gravada.

Comment: Qual forma você me indicaria para fazer isso ? tem algum exemplo ? estarei procurando sobre os assuntos citados , muito obrigado.

Comment: O estranho é que ele funcona perfeitamente se o menu tiver apenas 1 nível, mas quando ele tem subníveis ele não funciona.